# Plot CPU time vs iteration?

Tags: plotting, series-expansion, timing, date-and-time

I would like to generate a plot of CPU time vs number of iterations. For example, if I were to calculate the solution of a system of differential equations in state-space form using the summation of e^(A t) (or any series expansion for that matter):

```
A = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}
sol=Sum[(MatrixPower[A, j] t^j)  /j!, {j, 0, 200}]
```

I tried:

```
Table[Timing[N[Sum[(MatrixPower[A, j] t^j)  /j!, {j, 0, i}]]], {i, 0, 
  200}]
```

but this outputs the solution of the summation along with the time.  I only require the cpu time for each individual iteration and the iteration number. Can someone point me in the right direction here?

Comment: It's very intriguing that you've  managed the problem till this point but now you don't know how to plot it.

Comment: I never said I didn't know how to plot it, I asked how to plot the timing of each individual evaluation. But, thanks for not attempting to help nonetheless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
Table[First@Timing[N[Sum[(MatrixPower[A, j] t^j)/j!, {j, 0, i}]]], {i, 0, 200}]
ListLinePlot[%]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

If you want the iteration number side by side, just change the body of the `Table` to `{i, First@...}`.